# 'Rooms' button in Outlook

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, mapi

We have MAPI message store provider which handles mail, calendar and contact modules in Outlook. With our service provider Outlook profile, "Rooms" button is missing from Meeting compose windows. I have checked the documentation and unfortunately no information is available on this. How to show "Rooms" button in Meeting compose window for non exchange accounts?. Is "Rooms" button  available for non exchange accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Rooms" button makes any sense for Exchange accounts only.